# How to connect to the local database in eclipse?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I use Eclipse. My goal is to connect to the PostgreSQL database that I've already created on my machine and create some tables in it. As far as I understand I can do this by creating an sql file in Eclipse. Unfortunately, I don't figure out what to do after creating an SQL file so that I could connect to my database.

P.S. I managed to do this using JDBC:

```
package com.foxminded.table_builder;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.foxminded.table_model.CoursesTable;
import com.foxminded.table_model.GroupsTable;
import com.foxminded.table_model.StudentsTable;

public class TableBuilder {
    private static final String USER = "user1";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "01234";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school";
    StudentsTable studentsTable = new StudentsTable();
    GroupsTable groupsTable = new GroupsTable();
    CoursesTable coursesTable = new CoursesTable();
    
    
    public void buildTable() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()){
            statement.execute(studentsTable.buildTable());
            statement.execute(groupsTable.buildTable());
            statement.execute(coursesTable.buildTable());
        }finally {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But my question is "Is it possible to do the same through creating an SQL file"?

Comment: What do you mean with _"Is it possible to do the same through creating an SQL file"_? It is unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should have the Postgres JDBC driver for the using Java. You can download it from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html.

So now it's the Eclipse config:

1. Open DB Develpment Perspective Window > Open Perspective > Other > Database Development Perspective
2. Select PostgresSQL profile
3. Choose the driver you have downloaded
4. Enter the DB details in the wizard and press the "Test Connection" button to verify everything is ok.